# How do i use tkinter python to with phrase = input("ENTER TEXT ") Tkinter text boxes?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to give my code a gui but I don't know how to use inputs with tkinter text boxes.
The code I am trying to give a gui:

```
phrase = input("ENTER TEXT ")
print("YOU ENTERED " + phrase + " NUMBER OF LETTERS: ")
print(len(phrase))
print("CONVERTED TO LOWER CASE:")
print(phrase.lower())
print("CONVERTED TO UPPER CASE:")
print(phrase.upper())


def say_hi():
        print("BYE USER")
        input('Press ENTER to exit')
say_hi()
```

Comment: Before asking, your first step should be to work through a tkinter tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code perform exactly what you do using a tkinter GUI.

**Here is what you need to understand :**

- Label is used to create a paragraph.
- Entry is a text input widget.
- Entry has a get method to extract the tiped text.
- To overwrite existing text in an Entry, you use it's method delete. You have to specify a range to delete.
- To insert text in an Entry, you use it's method insert. You have to specify the position where the text will be inserted.

#### Code

```
import tkinter as tk

class YourGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # inherit tkinter's window methods
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        tk.Label(self, text="ENTER TEXT:")\
            .grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.input = tk.Entry(self)
        self.input.grid(row=0, column=1)

        tk.Label(self, text="CONVERTED TO LOWER CASE:")\
            .grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.result_lower = tk.Entry(self)
        self.result_lower.grid(row=1, column=1)

        tk.Label(self, text="CONVERTED TO UPPER CASE:")\
            .grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.result_upper = tk.Entry(self)
        self.result_upper.grid(row=2, column=1)

        tk.Button(self, text="convert", command=self.do_conversion)\
            .grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)



    def do_conversion(self):
        self.result_lower.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.result_upper.delete(0, tk.END)

        phrase = self.input.get()
        self.result_lower.insert(0, phrase.lower())
        self.result_upper.insert(0, phrase.upper())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    your_gui = YourGUI()
    your_gui.mainloop()
```

You should take a look at some tkinter tutorial like the following
https://likegeeks.com/python-gui-examples-tkinter-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little confusing, but this will open a message with an entry box.

```
import tkSimpleDialog
answer = tkSimpleDialog.askstring(title, message)
```

- The '**title**' parameter is simply the title of the message box, the text at the top.
- The '**message**' parameter is the message inside of the message box, such as 'Input your name'.

This is easier than other methods, as you do not need to setup a box, and position all the elements. However, if you need anything *but* a dialog box with an entry, you may want to try one of the other answers. :)

You can then use 'answer' however you need, exactly how you would with `input()`

~ Hope this helped! :D

Comment: By the way, don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the tick when you find an answer that works for you! Just letting you know, as you are a new contributor :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through Tkinter manual to see what kind of layout would be suitable for you. For above mentioned requirements, try this:

1. First import the library: `import tkinter as tk`
2. Then outside your main function/method/class: `root.mainloop()`
3. You can use tkinter grid layout. Try some example here: https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_layout_management.php
4. Then:

   `phraseLabel = Label(window, text = "ENTER TEXT").grid(row=1,column=1) #creates label`

   `phraseEntry = Entry(window, textvariable=phraseValue).grid(row=2,column=1) #create input text field`
5. To retrieve the value from the text field use: `phraseValue.get()`

Best wishes